# Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '239.6' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT     SerialNumber
FROM       [ETEL-PRDSQL].[ERP10DBLIVE].[ERP].[SerialNo]
WHERE      CustNum IN (2);
```

It's causing this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '239.6' to data type int.

The query works if I compare `CustNum` with a different value, but it fails when I try `CustNum IN (2)`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please edit your query and remove all of the fields in the SELECT portion that are not causing your problem?  I'm wasting my time looking through all this stuff trying to find `CustNum`.

Comment: Your error message states that it can't convert the string "239.6" to an int, which makes sense without some additional casting or conversion code. There are a variety of ways to turn your 239.6 into something which could be converted to an int correctly, but that depends on your intent.  I cannot tell WHERE in your code you are getting this error though

Comment: Try to focus on the `M` in [`MRE`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If there's a decimal point, it's not an int

Comment: Is SerialNumber defined somewhere as an int?  Should it be?

Answer (score 1):

You have a `varchar` column named `CustNum`. The `varchar` values in this column may contain only digits, **but that doesn't make them numbers!** Then you compare this text column with the integer value `2`. Again, the integer value `2` is *not the same* as the text value `'2'`. It's also not the same as the floating point value `2.0`. These are all different, they have different types, and SQL Server must resolve any such differences before it can compare values.

Based on [type precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) SQL Server determines it needs to convert the text in the column to the integer, instead of vice versa. Once this determination is made for the query, if you have any data in the text column that is not **integer**-compatible, the query is going to fail.

It's important to understand this conversion happens separately from the conditional check in the WHERE clause, and is a prerequisite for that check. It's not enough to expect the WHERE condition to evaluate to FALSE for rows that do not convert. This is true even if you don't need the row, because SQL Server can't know you don't need that row until after it attempts the conversion!

In this case, we have the value `293.6`. This value may be numeric, but it is not an integer. Nor is it convertible to integer. Therefore the query fails.

In addition to (eventually!) failing the query, this is absolutely awful for performance. SQL Server has to do this conversion **for every row in the table**... even rows you don't need. This is because SQL Server doesn't know which rows will match the WHERE clause until after it checks the conditional expression, and it needs to do this conversion in order to make that check. Worse still, the new converted value no longer matches your indexes, so any indexes you might have become worthless for this query. That cuts to the core of database performance.

If you don't like it, define your data types better, or trying comparing the string with another string:

```
SELECT     SerialNumber
FROM       [ETEL-PRDSQL].[ERP10DBLIVE].[ERP].[SerialNo]
WHERE      CustNum IN ('2');
```

The query might also run if you did this:

```
SELECT     SerialNumber
FROM       [ETEL-PRDSQL].[ERP10DBLIVE].[ERP].[SerialNo]
WHERE      CustNum IN (2.0);
```

Now the type precedence rules will convert your text to a floating point type, and it's possible that will succeed if the rest of the values in the table are compatible. It's also possible this is closer to what you intend... but again, the performance here will be much worse.